# Parent/Child(ren) Hierarchy / "Nested Sets", in Python/Django

Tags: python, django, parent-child, hierarchy

I'm using Django/Python, but pseudo-code is definitely acceptable here.

Working with some models that already exist, I have `Employee`s that each have a `Supervisor`, which is essentially a Foreign Key type relationship to another `Employee`.

Where the Employee/Supervisor hierarchy is something like this:

Any given Employee has ONE Supervisor. That Supervisor may have one or more Employees "beneath", and has his/her own Supervisor as well. Retrieving my "upline" should return my supervisor, his supervisor, her supervisor, etc., until reaching an employee that has no supervisor.

Without going hog-wild and installing new apps to manage these relationships, as this is an existing codebase and project, I'm wondering the "pythonic" or correct way to implement the following functions:

```
def get_upline(employee): 
    # Get a flat list of Employee objects that are
    # 'supervisors' to eachother, starting with 
    # the given Employee. 
    pass


def get_downline(employee):
    # Starting with the given Employee, find and 
    # return a flat list of all other Employees 
    # that are "below". 
    pass
```

I feel like there may be a somewhat simple way to do this with the Django ORM, but if not, I'll take any suggestions.

I haven't thoroughly checked out Django-MPTT, but if I can leave the models in tact, and simply gain more functionality, it would be worth it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to touch your models to be able to use django-mptt; you just have to create a `parent` field on your model, django-mptt creates all the other attributes for mptt automaitcally, when you register your model: `mptt.register(MyModel)`.

Though if you just need the 'upline' hierarchy you wouldn't need nested sets. The bigger performance problem is going the opposite direction and collect eg. children/leaves etc, which makes it necessary to work on a nested set model!

Comment: Realistically, the "upline"/parents list is much more vital than children. What is the simple approach to that? Would it still be faster to read docs/implement djang-mptt?

Comment: Actually you need four new fields for mptt: `parent`, `level`, `left` and `right`.

Answer (score 0):

Relational databases are not good for this kind of graph queries, so your only option is to do a bunch of query.  Here is a recursive implementation:

```
def get_upline(employee):
    if self.supervisor:
        return [employee] + self.supervisor.get_upline()
    else:
        return [employee]

def get_download(employee):
    l = [employee]
    for minion in self.minion_set.all():
        l.extend(minion.get_download())
    return l
```

Comment: Would I need to add a check for an empty `supervisor` in `get_upline()` here? I'm imagining an Exception or something happening when the root is reached. Am I wrong?

Comment: Vebjorn, can you explain where `self.minion_set.all()` comes from, please?

Comment: @TommyGibbons, it's a Django [RelatedManager](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/relations/) for a relation named "minion".

Comment: @Vebjorn Ljosa. By _relation_ am I correct to understand as a class in models.py or a table in a db?  If that is the case, is it fair to say that an FK in the `minion` is pointing to the PK in `employee`.    From here a `dir (employee)` will return  `minion_set`  as one parameter.  I am just trying to get this structure clear in my head.

Comment: @TommyGibbons: Correct (if I understand you correctly).

Comment: @Vebjorn Ljosa: I have `class EmployeeDynamic`, FK to Employee, FK to User (Django Admin User). Using `dir (EmployeeDynamic)` does not return a `user_set`.  I am trying to list all employees in the Supervisor - Supervisor - employee chain.

Comment: @TommyGibbons: You'll only see `…_set` on the "many" side of a many-to-one relationship. If the foreign key to User is in EmployeeDynamic (so you have a user_id column in the app_employeedynamic table in the database), then the "many" side is the User side. You should probably draw an E-R diagram and make sure you're clear about the database side of things before mixing in the confusing Django bits.

Comment: "mixing in the confusing Django bits."   Yep, got it. Thanks.